# Show certain amount of characters from a column in Flask

Tags: sql, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Currently I have a big block of text called 'bigtext'.  This can range from a few hundred words to a few thousand words.

I'm currently displaying this column on a webpage by iterating over the rows in Flask.

```
{{ % for row in rows % }}
{{ row.bigtext }}
{{ row.name }}
```

However, I would only like to show the first say 100 characters of this column rather than the full text.  Is there a way I can do this?

At the moment I have something like:

```
THIS GIANT PIECE OF BLOCK TEXT.THIS GIANT PIECE OF BLOCK TEXT. THIS GIANT PIECE OF BLOCK TEXT.THIS GIANT PIECE OF BLOCK TEXT
```

But I'd like it to be like:

```
THIS GIANT PIECE OF BLOCK TEXT.
```

Or however many characters I want it to be.

I know the raw SQL query would be to use SUBSTR but now sure how to incorporate this into my Flask app?

Thank you

Comment: You could use a slicer, e.g. `{{ row.bigtext[0:100] }}`.

Comment: Use [truncate](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#truncate) to shorten the text and to indicate that it is longer in the original. `{{ row.bigtext | truncate(100) }}`